# How can I make a method that, when run, checks what resource is in an ImageView and then changes it depending in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am designing a Hangman app in Android. I am relatively new to android and Java so simple explanations are appreciated.
I want to have a method that runs when the player chooses a wrong letter, I already have the hangman mechanics working, but I can't get a method to change what drawable an ImageView is displaying each time the method is run.  I have been trying to make it set a new image depending on what image is currently displayed, but an alternate approach would be to have it cycle through images, but I couldn't figure that out.  Any help is appreciated.

```
    public void switchImage(View view) {
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setTag("0");
    if (img.getTag() == "0") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gallows1);
        img.setTag("1");
    } else if (img.getTag() == "1") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gallows2);
        img.setTag("2");
    } else if (img.getTag() == "2") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gallows3);
        img.setTag("3");
    } else if (img.getTag() == "3") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gallows4);
        img.setTag("4");
    } else if (img.getTag() == "4") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gallows5);
        img.setTag("5");
    } else if (img.getTag() == "5") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gallows6);
        img.setTag("6");
    } else if (img.getTag() == "6") {
        return;
    }
}
```

^That's my current code, I realize it won't work because of the scope of the Tag but I have spent a long time trying ways to fix that so I think that maybe using view tags isn't the best approach. Thank you.

Comment: `it won't work because of the scope of the Tag`???  The scope of the tag is identical to `img` since it is just as property of it.  If you want to cycle, why not add a class field, e.g. `int currentImage = 0;` then in your switchImage method, `currentImage ++;`?

Comment: But when I setTag inside the if statement, that Tag doesn't last to the next else if, right? I tried using nested loops and instead of only working the first time like this one it just went straight to the last image.

Comment: Surely you need to remove this line: img.setTag("0");

Comment: That will just make it not do anything at all.

Comment: @Simon I think that would work but I only want it to switch the image once each time the method is run, so how do I make it not just loop to the last image the first time, or will your suggestion take care of that?

Comment: tpbapp is half right, not remove it just move it, the tag should be initially set to "0" at the start of the game of hangman not in the switchImage method

Comment: Drop tags and `if` statements altogether. Use this `setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("gallows" + currentImage, "drawable","<put your packagename here>"));`

Comment: @triggs I see what you mean, but if define the imageView outside the method and set the tag to 0 in onCreate I get an error when I open the activity, I'm going to try using LevelListDrawable as fbenedet suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html, define in xml which image you should be show.
mxl:

```
'<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/cont_big_50"
        android:maxLevel="5"
        android:minLevel="5"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/cont_big_40"
        android:maxLevel="4"
        android:minLevel="4"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/cont_big_30"
        android:maxLevel="3"
        android:minLevel="3"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/cont_big_20"
        android:maxLevel="2"
        android:minLevel="2"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/cont_big_10"
        android:maxLevel="1"
        android:minLevel="1"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cont_big_00"/>

</level-list>'
```

in java:
imageview.setImageLevel()

Comment: So I made an xml in drawables that with each drawable I want to use as an item, with the first item's max and min as 0, going up to 6 as the last.  I wrote this method to switch the image but if doesn't seem to work: public void nextGallows() {
  int i = 0;
  ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageLevel(i);
  i++;
 }   //what am I doing wrong here?  I call this method each time the wrong letter is chosen

Comment: can you post xml file? you need set xml in imageview:  android:src="@drawable/cont_big"

Answer (score 0):

No need to store your data (game state) in the ImageView (which breaks the MVC pattern). That's error prone and convoluted.

You can do it more cleanly (robustly) like this.

```
private int mGallowsState=0;
private static final int[] GALLOWS_IMG_RESOURCES = {
    R.drawable.gallows1,
    R.drawable.gallows2,
    R.drawable.gallows3,
    R.drawable.gallows4,
    R.drawable.gallows5,
    R.drawable.gallows6 };

public void incrementGallows(){

    mGallowsState = (mGallowsState+1) % GALLOWS_IMG_RESOURCES.length;
    //The "% GALLOWS_IMG_RESOURCES.length" is only if you want to cycle it around
    //The alternative would be to immediately return if 
    //(mGallowsState >= GALLOWS_IMG_RESOURCES.length)

    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
        .setImageResource(GALLOWS_IMG_RESOURCES[mGallowsState]);
}
```